# How to create Eloquent relationship model to compare a data in a nested array of column?

Tags: mongodb, laravel

my collection structure as follows

```
collection name:general_details
{
    "id": 01,
    "personal_details":[
        [
            "emp_id":10,
            "blood_group":"B+ve"
        ],
        [
            "emp_id":11,
            "blood_group":"B+ve"
        ]
    ]
}

collection name:employee_details
{
    "emp_id":10,
    "emp_name":"Alex"
},
{
    "emp_id":11,
    "emp_name":"Ramesh"
}
```

i want to create an eloquent relationship model for emp_id between the collections.

Comment: MongoDB is not a relational database but you may still use DBRefs, [check here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)

Comment: we are using jenssegers